# Highstock returns incorrect Width after print

Tags: highcharts

my highstock is sitting in a Div and the div has Width="90%" so the chart is spread over all width.

after printing the Width of the chart is becoming so narrow that you can't see anything,

at run time i get :

Error: Invalid negative value for  attribute width="-1" highstock.js:52

**any idea?**

Comment: Recreate issue on jsFiddle. About Error in console, bug in 4.0.1 version, true to use candidate for 4.0.2: http://github.highcharts.com/master/highcharts.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i add this: and it works perfect!

```
 #container
        {
            height: 500px;
            min-width: 310px;
            max-width: 800px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        .loading
        {
            margin-top: 10em;
            text-align: center;
            color: gray;
        }
```